# EE4 Training Available?

Tags: ee4

It's been a while since I've developed an EE site, and I'd like to develop an EE4 site soon using modern best practices. Can anyone recommend courses, training, or anything of the sort to prepare me for this? Something like http://www.train-ee.com/ but for EE4.

Comment: Unfortunatly, exist only courses, books about EE2. If you ever used EE2, reading the EE4 documentation will not difficult to use.EE4 .

Comment: I see what you mean. But Ellislab has promoted a whole lot of new stuff since EE2: layouts, fluid field types, etc., since then, and I'd like to know in real world cases where/how this is used. I'll just do my best. They have a "build a basic news site" in the documentation that I'll do, at least.